# ¿Es posible lanzar un correo automático programado en Apps Script desde un correo distinto al mio (ejecutador)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-simple-triggers

Tengo ya un código heredado en Apps Script, el cual lo que hace es que envía un correo único automático (template) una vez que alguien responde a un formulario (google forms).

El problema es que el correo de donde sale es desde mi personal, y lo que quiero es que se ejecute desde un buzón genérico de la empresa, esto es posible? y cómo lo consigo? es necesario modificar algún código o cual me ayudaría?

Esto tiene que ver con el activador **installtrigger**? porque entiendo que es tema de permisos.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: buenos días, tu pregunta no se adata a la política de stackoverflow , le envió un video de como se puede configura la notificación https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDvdo8Sa6LA, debido que llenar el formulario por google forms es muy limitado la operación

Answer (score 0):

Sí es posible, y hay varias formas de hacerlo. La más sencilla es crear el activador instalable usando la cuenta desde la cual deseas enviar el email.

Otra opción relativamente sencilla es que la dirección que deseas usar para el envío del correo, la agregues a tu cuenta de Gmail como "alias", luego en Apps Script usarías el método [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) indicando en el objeto `options` la dirección a usar como remitente en la propiedad `from`.

Otra opción es hacer uso de la API de Gmail y de la autenticación mediante OAuth.